# How do I open audio settings GUI in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: sound, 20.10

In ubuntu 18 audio settings were here:

[image]

Now in ubuntu 20 these settings seem to be gone:

[image]

where should I find them?

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases with the format *yy.mm* (eg. 20.04) and *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20). Please clarify your release, there is no Ubuntu 20, do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu Core 20, or your tagged 20.10 as releases using format *yy* are different products to *yy.mm* releases.  Are you running your desktop as a *snap* (as in a *yy* release) or via *deb* packages (a *yy.mm* release)?  They differ.

Comment: you're showing the settings app where basic settings of each app are shown - you're showing the basic app settings for the "settings app" -> in the settings app go the "sound" settings and not to "app settings"

Answer (score 1):

search "sound" in "app search"

click on super key (= windows key on windows keyboard) to get to app search

[image: search sound]

select "Sound" section of settings app

[image: setting - Sound]

Comment: or type "gnome-control-center sound" in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

One answer can be the one given by @Koen. But there is another sound settings app, called Pulse Audio Volume Control. It must be with the installation. If it isn't there, install it using `sudo apt install pavucontrol`. Here is a screenshot here on my Xubuntu system:[image]